# Spliting content by not so clear marker - PHP preg_spllit or explode

Tags: php, split, explode

I have this string (file content) with sections:

```
0
3
1
Ref-1
5-18-100 Xeeecooo



-1

0
11
1
FK-1567
88-158-62 Maxco




-1

0
5
.....
```

that always are same when number of rows is considered.

I need to break those sections (so I can tweek the internal lines of each) and the marker here is `-1`
After bunch of tries with `explode` and `preg_match` I am still nowhere.

eg.
`preg_split( "/^-1$/m", $file_content);`

Is there a way to achieve what I've been trying to achieve?

Comment: Try to explode on `"\n-1\n"`.

Comment: I did try that, with no luck. But the below solution works perfectly!
Thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow an arbitrary number of whitespace characters (but at least one) with `\s+` (space, new lines, ...) before and after the `-1` with this expression :

```
$res = preg_split( "/\s+-1\s+/", $file_content);
```

Comment: I won't even start guessing why the regular `-1` didn't work, for the time being I am very grateful I have the solution. **This worked like a charm**. Thank you lots!

Comment: Maybe an encoding problem ? on Windows, I need to add the carriage return character `\r` before the `$` to have matches : `/^-1\r$/m`. The `\s` handle all these thing in a single expression.